# Install local dist package into virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a pytest test, let's call it `test.py`. I used to run this test outside of virtualenv; now I'm trying to run it inside a virtualenv sandbox.

The project is structured like this:

```
~/project/test # where test.py and all virtualenv files live
~/project/mylibrary
```

`test.py` imports from `mylibrary`. In the past, this worked because I have the code in `~/project/mylibrary` installed into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mylibrary`.

I can't run virtualenv with the `--system-site-packages` flag. I also can't move the code from `~/project/mylibrary` into the `~/project/test` folder. How can I get access to the code in mylibrary inside my virtualenv?

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py`? Could you just install it within the `virtualenv`?

Comment: mylibrary does have a setup.py. How would I install it inside `virtualenv`?

Comment: ...`python setup.py install`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special - as long as you are working inside a virtualenv, `python setup.py install` will automatically install packages into

```
$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

rather than your system-wide

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

directory.

In general it's better to use `pip install mylibrary/`, since this way you can neatly uninstall the package using `pip uninstall mylibrary`.

If you're installing a working copy of some code that you're developing, it might be a good idea to install it in ["editable" mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) using `pip install -e mylibrary/`, which creates a link to your source directory so that your installed module gets updated as you edit the code.

Comment: `pip install /path/to/mypackage/` worked, when `python setup.py install` gave me a `can't find '__main__' module` error

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6193999/1461210)? It would be hard for me to figure out what's going on without seeing your source directory and your `setup.py`.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way would be to add the directory containing the library to your `sys.path`

Comment: This is not necessarily the best as this could mess up other programs that are running on that host that have a conflict with that package